# Add only one row from a PostGIS layer to geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I have a PostGIS table with 50 rows/entries. 
Is it possible to add this 50 entries to 50 geoserver layers (1 layer = 1 row of the table)?

Comment: Use the views : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as @juls says you can use a view to filter by ID (or other unique attribute). But really why would you?

Comment: Views is a great idea :) I use a python ORM (sqlalchemy) and It would make things easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create SQL Views directly in GeoServer:

[See](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_sqllayers.html)